# COM class cannot be found when running .net code from Matlab

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, com

I'm using c# do build a few libraries which we then use from within Matlab 64bit. The c# library is compiled to 64bit so that we can use it from Matlab. The c# library uses an interop to call a COM component which is legacy 32bit code. When running the tests in c# everything works but if I use the library from Matlab I get the following error:

**Message: Unable to cast COM object of type '...' to interface type '...'. This operation failed because the
QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{...}' failed due to the following
error: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
Source: mscorlib**

To me it looks like the runtime is looking for the 64bit of the COM class but I don't understand why but afaik visual studio 2017 is still 32 bit thats why it is picking the right COM. Any help is welcome.

**UPDATE**

I tried to run the code using a 64bit test loaded and I get the same error, so it was running from VS because it is 32bit. Having identified that, is there a way to force a 64bit execution context to call 32bit COM components?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97672-32-bit-dll-com-64-bit-matlab

Comment: @kunif what made you think that I know how to read japanese? And Matlab i know how to call COM components from Matlab, what I'm struggling with is being able to use 32bit COMs from c# which is then used by Matlab. Matlab only uses .net code. Thanks a lot for your help anyway.

Comment: alternatively, https://techtalk.gfi.com/32bit-object-64bit-environment/

Comment: @kunif I saw that one, but it's a hack and prone to so many issues, even a windows update can break that. I decided to build a desktop daemon as a wrapper to all those legacy COMs. Thanks